# multiple domains - one django project

Tags: python, django, django-views

I want to run ONE django project on multiple domains/websites. The websites each need to access a unique "urls.py"/"views.py". I tried it already with [this tutorial](http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2010/10/19/run-multiple-websites-one-django-project/), but it doesn't work for me.
Is there a way to do this with middleware in an easy way (without the Sites framework)?
A little bit of help would be really great. Thanks.

Edit: As I tried it like in the tutorial from above, my httpd.conf looked like this:

```
ServerRoot "/home/webfactionusername/webapps/erdbeer/apache2"

LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule dir_module        modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module        modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module       modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule rewrite_module    modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module   modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule wsgi_module       modules/mod_wsgi.so
LoadModule unixd_module      modules/mod_unixd.so

LogFormat "%{X-Forwarded-For}i %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
CustomLog /home/webfactionusername/logs/user/access_erdbeer.log combined
ErrorLog /home/webfactionusername/logs/user/error_erdbeer.log

Listen 10414
KeepAlive Off
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-SSL on HTTPS=1
ServerLimit 1
StartServers 1
MaxRequestWorkers 5
MinSpareThreads 1
MaxSpareThreads 3
ThreadsPerChild 5

WSGIDaemonProcess erdbeer processes=2 threads=12 python-path=/home/webfactionusername/webapps/erdbeer:/home/webfactionusername/webapps/erdbeer/myproject:/home/webfactionusername/webapps/erdbeer/lib/python2.7
WSGIProcessGroup erdbeer
WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
WSGILazyInitialization On
WSGIScriptAlias / /home/webfactionusername/webapps/erdbeer/myproject/myproject/wsgi.py


# Virtual hosts setup
NameVirtualHost *
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName mydomain123abc.de

    WSGIDaemonProcess erdbeer processes=5 python-path=/home/webfactionusername/webapps/erdbeer:/home/webfactionusername/webapps/erdbeer/lib/python2.7 threads=1
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/webfactionusername/webapps/erdbeer/subdomain1.wsgi
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName seconddomain123.de

    WSGIDaemonProcess erdbeer processes=5 python-path=/home/webfactionusername/webapps/erdbeer:/home/webfactionusername/webapps/erdbeer/lib/python2.7 threads=1
    WSGIScriptAlias / /home/webfactionusername/webapps/erdbeer/subdomain2.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

Edit2: I'm still not able to grasp this middleware-concept. I only was able to understand how that I probably need to use "process_request", but I have no clue how the middleware-file would look like. Lets say I have "domain1.com" and "domain2.com" which should use these urls:

domain1_urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import HttpResponse

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'myapp1.views.home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^robots\.txt$', lambda r: HttpResponse("User-agent: *\nDisallow:", content_type="text/plain")),
]
```

domains2_urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.http import HttpResponse

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', 'myapp2.views.home'),
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^robots\.txt$', lambda r: HttpResponse("User-agent: *\nDisallow:", content_type="text/plain")),
]
```

How would I use that in my middleware? (I'm a beginner...)

Comment: It will work. May be web server conf issues.Post your web server configuration

Comment: I edited my post. I would like to do it with Middleware, if possible as I don't know anything about Apache and stuff like that.

Comment: Do you need diiferent settings for different domains ?

Comment: No. The settings are the same. But the urls and views won't be.

Comment: Take a look at middlewares. Inside middleware you will get domain and url.Check that domain has access to that url.Then do redirects based on that.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution [perfectly here](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/MultiHostMiddleware).

```
# File: settings.py

HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP = {
    # Control Panel
    "www.example.com": "webapp.sites.example.urls",
}
```

and

```
# File: multihost.py

import time
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.cache import patch_vary_headers

class MultiHostMiddleware:

    def process_request(self, request):
        try:
            request.META["LoadingStart"] = time.time()
            host = request.META["HTTP_HOST"]
            #if host[-3:] == ":80":
            #    host = host[:-3] # ignore default port number, if present

            # best way to do this.
            host_port = host.split(':')
            if len(host_port)==2:                    
                host = host_port[0] 

            if host in settings.HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP:
                request.urlconf = settings.HOST_MIDDLEWARE_URLCONF_MAP[host]
                request.META["MultiHost"] = str(request.urlconf)
            else:
                request.META["MultiHost"] = str(settings.ROOT_URLCONF)

        except KeyError:
            pass # use default urlconf (settings.ROOT_URLCONF)

    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if 'MultiHost' in request.META:
            response['MultiHost'] = request.META.get("MultiHost")

        if 'LoadingStart' in request.META:
            _loading_time = time.time() - int(request.META["LoadingStart"])
            response['LoadingTime'] = "%.2fs" % ( _loading_time, )

        if getattr(request, "urlconf", None):
            patch_vary_headers(response, ('Host',))
        return response
```